# "list index out of range" when iterating through a csv file

Tags: python, csv

A strange thing is happening over here, I'm trying to add two extra line to an existing csv file, so I open it (edit1.csv), re-write it to a new file (edit2) with two extra line (one with the number 100 written on the first space, and a second row with the number 9 in the first three space.

```
ifile  = open('C:\PyProject\edit1.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
edited  = open('C:\PyProject\edit2.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(edited, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
writer.writerow([100])
writer.writerow('999')
edited.close()
ifile.close()
```

So far so good, I get a new file (edit2.csv) that looks exactly like I want it to look.

The problem is when I'm trying to iterate through the new file in order to find the rows in which the second column is empty (see below), I get an error

-

```
with open('C:\PyProject\edit2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    sec_col = []
    for row in readCSV:
        blanker = row[1]
        sec_col.append(blanker)
    trial_index = [i for i,x in enumerate(sec_col) if x == '']
```

-

```
  blanker = row[1]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

The strange thing is that if i open the new file and delete all the blank rows after the two I have manually added, the code runs just fine.

Sorry if my code is a bit messy, I'm still new at this :)

Thanks.

Comment: Solved, added [100,"",""] instead of just 100. Sorry for posting such a trivial problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only wrong part is accessing `row[1]` directly.

If row has only 1 row, then it throws exception when you are trying to reach the second.

Just modify the code like this:

```
for row in readCSV:
    if len(row) < 2: # row[1] not exists
        sec_col.append(row)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. sec_col only gets the value of 100, which is the line I have added manually, but doesn't get the value of all other rows that have only 1 value in them.  Other than that, the original code did find the rows with one value in them, but not the row that I have added in the end (with 100 in it).

Comment: And it still doesn't explain why my code managed to work perfectly when I went and manually deleted all blank rows in the csv file using excel. Thanks for trying to help, if you have any more ideas I would gladly try them.